# How to save xml output in a file without xml::smart package

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to save xml output to xml file without smart package but not able to do it.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Simple;

my $xml;
my @hash = qw('test' '60.0' 'test1' '103' 'test2' '20' 'test3' '108');

my %hash1 =@hash;

my $hash2 = \%hash1;

my $xs = new XML::Simple;
$xml = $xs->XMLout($hash2 ,
                  NoAttr => 1,
                  RootName=>'newPhone',
                  );
print $xml;
$xml->save('newfile.xml') ;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no magic `save` method in [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple).  If you try your code, you will get an error message that tells you this:

```
Can't locate object method "save" via package "<newPhone>..."
```

Instead, to output to a file, you simply need to open a filehandle and print to it:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use autodie;

use XML::Simple;

my %hash = qw(test 60.0 test1 103 test2 20 test3 108);;

my $xs = new XML::Simple;
my $xml = $xs->XMLout(\%hash,
     NoAttr    => 1,
     RootName  => 'newPhone',
);

open my $fh, '>', 'newfile.xml';
print $fh $xml;
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Simple;

my $xml;
my @hash = qw('test' '60.0' 'test1' '103' 'test2' '20' 'test3' '108');

my %hash1 =@hash;

my $hash2 = \%hash1;

my $xs = new XML::Simple;
$xml = $xs->XMLout($hash2 ,
                  NoAttr => 1,
                                    RootName=>'newPhone',
                                                      );
#print $xml;
open (FH, '>newfile.xml') || die "unable to create $!";
$xml = qq{<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n} . $xml;
print FH $xml;
close (FH);
```

Comment: modern Perl style frowns upon bareword filehandle, which can lead to hard to trace bugs if the same filehandle is used elsewhere in the code, and 2 args `open`, especially in this case where you probably want the output to be utf-8 encoded. So the open statement should probably be `open( my $fh, '>:utf8', 'newfile.xml')`, the print `print {$fh} $xml` and the close `close $fh`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using my [`XML::MyXML`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::MyXML) module, which saves, has no dependencies, and is okay for small XML documents.